# Problema al recorrer el json obtenido con ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo este código `HTML` para consumir `JSON` mediante `ajax`, pero no me muestra los datos que quiero traer.

¿Me podrían decir que estoy haciendo mal?

El `url` del `JSON` es este: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a5502052d0000f43a5b1e60*

Este es el `script` que esto usando:

```
<div class="panel-heading">Programa</div>
<div class="panel-body" id="programas"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () 
    {
         $.ajax({
             url: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5a5502052d0000f43a5b1e60',
             type: 'GET',
             dataType: 'JSON',
             success: function (data) 
             {
                 var program = "<ul>";
                 for (var c = 0; c < data.length; c++) {
                     var infoprograma = "<li>" + "Programa: "+  data[c].programa[0].programa;
                     infoprograma += "Sinopsis: " + data[c].programa[0].sinopsis;
                     infoprograma += "Conductor: " + data[c].programa[0].conductor;
                     infoprograma += "Clasificacion: " + data[c].programa[0].clasificacion;
                     infoprograma += " <em>" + data[c].programa[0].tipoProgram + "</em> </li>";
                     program += infoprograma; 
                 }
                 program += "</ul>";
                 $("#programas").html(infoprograma);
             }
             })
    });
</script>
```

Cuando doy a `Network > Preview` me muestra objeto que estoy llamando, pero en el `div` no me muestra nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow Mateo! Para poder darte una mano con el problema deberías especificar si estás teniendo un error y especificarlo. en el caso de que no veas el error, prueba haciendo un console.log(data), para que que te devuelve la llamada.

Comment: ningún erro pero cuando boy a Network, preview me muestra el json que estoy llamando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `data` es un objeto y lo estas intentando iterar mediante `data.length`. Dicha propiedad no existe por lo que es igual a `undefined`. Lo que necesitas iterar es la propiedad `programa`.

### Solución:

El `for` deberías hacerlo sobre `data.programa.length` y acceder a los datos del programa usando `data.programa[c].*`

### Ejemplo:

```
success: function(data) {
  var program = "<ul>";
  for (var c = 0; c < data.programa.length; c++) {
    var infoprograma = "<li>" + "Programa: " + data.programa[c].programa;
    infoprograma += "Sinopsis: " + data.programa[c].sinopsis;
    infoprograma += "Conductor: " + data.programa[c].conductor;
    infoprograma += "Clasificacion: " + data.programa[c].clasificacion;
    infoprograma += " <em>" + data.programa[c].tipoProgram + "</em> </li>";
    program += infoprograma;
  }
  program += "</ul>";
  $("#programas").html(infoprograma);
}
```

Comment: gracias me sirvio